# Surround html with Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="post-container" id="<%= folder.id %>">
                        <%= link_to 'Folder ' + folder.id.to_s, folder_path(folder), :remote => true %>
                        <%= folder.title %> <p id="created-time">Created <%= folder.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %></p>
                    </div>
```

It calls a JavaScript file and injects a partial into view. What I'd like to do is surround the whole div with that `link_to` which is currently inside the div. Adding "do" before the final `%` doesn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started.

```
<%= link_to folder_path(folder), remote: true do %>
  <%= content_tag :div, id: folder.id, class: 'post-container' do %>
    Folder <%= folder.id.to_s %>
    <p id='created-time'>
      Created <%= folder.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to your_path do %>
  your html/ruby here
<% end %>
```

exemple from api:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
```

result in:

```
<a href="/profiles/1">
  <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

and if you open the link this way, you should not have another `link_to` inside:

**wrong:**

```
<%= link_to your_path do %>
  <%= link_to 'folder', folder_path %>
<% end %>
```

won't work as it will be a link inside link.

it has to be something like this:

```
<%= link_to folder_path(folder), :remote => true %>
  <div class="post-container" id="<%= folder.id %>">
    <%= folder.title %>
    <p id="created-time">Created <%= folder.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you look at my code? Adding "do" after the path or at the end before the % doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I did looked at your code!! may be you put `do` in the `end` tag, how the f.. should I guess where you did you put `do`, you'll be amazed how many interesting things people sometimes do, you just added your html code and tell us it doesn't work, it doesn't work how? gives you errors? not showing up.. how exactly it doesn't work? what rails version your app uses? we should guess this one too?